# How to count Child table to same with parent table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to count the student name field.
i have three table
**table 1**
invoice

```
invoice_id  student course_id timing_id day_id
```

**table 2**
course

```
course_id course_name
```

**table 3**
timing

```
timing_id time
```

**table 4**
days

```
days_id name
```

I want to count the number of students that are in one course, in same timing, in same day from invoice table

what is the query?

**view , model, controller?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn **Group by** and **Having** in mysql then you can solve this problem